# Different Between Static Mutext and Not Static Mutex

Tags: c++, mutex

I have a code in .cpp

```
namespapce A
{
    namespace
    {
        static CMutex initMutex;
    }

    void init()
    {
        //code here
    }

    void uninit()
    {
        //code here
    }
}
```

What is the different if I remove the static in the mutex and if there is a static? And what is the use of the static?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the `namespace` intentionally unnamed?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623451/static-vs-non-static-variables-in-namespace

Comment: Yes, its anonymous namespace so that other code can't use it.

Comment: `static` changes the linkage of the variable. It's for you to decide whether or not you want static linkage (e.g. is the code in a header or in a source file).

Comment: IS this code in header or cpp file?

Comment: Then static should be fine.

Comment: So what is the use of that static in the code? So I just created initMutex object?

Comment: If it is in the header and included in 2 cpp files. The lock applied by the code in first file will not be seen by the second file which is dangerous. This is because the 2 units has separate static of the mutex

Answer (score 5):

If mutex is static and if it would have been in the header and that header included in 2 cpp files(2 translational units), the lock applied by the code in first file will not be seen by the second file which is dangerous. This is because the 2 units has separate static of the mutex. In that case a global mutex is preferable.

If this is C++ then use RAII mechanism to manage mutex lock and unlock. THis is c++, where is the class? Encapsulate things into a class.

RAII example (basic one, things can be encapsulated into class):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization

Comment: "THis is c++, where is the class? Encapsulate things into a class." C++ doesn't says to cram everything into class, namespaces and free standing functions are fine by themselves, if used correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You are Kind of mixing up C and C++. The keyword `static` in C has the intention to narrow the scope of a variable down to the translation unit. You could define it globally in the translation unit, but it was not visible to other translation-units.
Bjarne Stroustrup recommends to use anonymous `namespaces` in C++ instead of using `static` like in C.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154469/unnamed-anonymous-namespaces-vs-static-functions) post it says

The C++ Standard reads in section 7.3.1.1 Unnamed namespaces, paragraph 2:

```
The use of the static keyword is deprecated when declaring objects 
in a namespace scope, the unnamed-namespace provides a superior alternative.
```

Static only applies to names of objects, functions, and anonymous unions, not to type declarations.

Answer (score 2):

static merely does two things:

- makes a variable to exist for the entire life of a program (but this is global level, so anything here exist for the whole program life!)
- makes a variable visible only in the translation unit it is declared (but this apply to whatever is in an anonymous namespace).

So, in fact, **in this particular context**, **static does nothing**.