# Static variables and different namespaces in c++

Tags: c++, static, namespaces

I have read on static variables and know what they are, how they function when define in a .cpp file, function, and class.

But I have slight confusion when define in different namespaces in the same cpp file.

One of these voted answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11623473/12641983) says:

> When you declare a variable as static inside a .h file (within or without namespace; doesn't matter), and include that header file in various .cpp files, the static variable becomes locally scoped to each of the .cpp files.

According to the program below, namespaces does matter.

```
static int a = 0;
namespace hello1 {
static int a = 1;
namespace hello2 { static int a = 2;}
namespace hello3 { static int a = 3;}
}
int main()
{
    std::cout<<::a<<hello1::a<<hello1::hello2::a<<hello1::hello3::a;
    return 0;
}
```

output
`0123`

Here is what I think: `a` outside namespaces is the file scope. `a` in hello1 is hello1 scope. Since hello1 is global scope namespace, I can only have one `a` in namespace hello1, including other cpp files where hello1 exists. The same goes for hello2 and hello3; only one `a` in each hello1::hello2 and hello1::hello3.

Please correct me If I understood it correct. The namespace does matter; static variables in the same cpp file under different namespaces are different entities.

Comment: _"The namespace does matter; static variables in the same cpp file under different namespaces are different entities."_ yes they are. Nothing to do with the files though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not what the passage you quoted is talking about.  It is referring to the fact that `static` variable names have internal-linkage.  What that means is that you can't access a `static` variable `a` that is defined in "a.cpp" from "b.cpp", even if you include a declaration of `a` in "b.cpp".  That declaration will refer to a different object.

For example:

A.hpp

```
static int a = 0;
void foo();
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.hpp"
#include <iostream>

void foo() { std::cout << a << '\n'; }
```

B.cpp

```
#include "A.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << a << '\n';  // prints 0
    a = 1;
    foo(); // prints 0, since it uses a different a
}
```

In this example, "A.cpp" and "B.cpp" see *different* global-scope objects named `a` since `a` was declared `static`.  Even though `main` modifies `a`'s value to be `1`, `foo` still sees it as `0` since it's looking at a different `a`.

This behavior is irrespective of namespaces.  If `a` were in a namespace other than the global namespace this same behavior would occur.  That is what the passage you quoted is referring to.

Comment: @ MilesBudnek: I know the reference link in the question belongs to slightly different topic. But there was this phrase "within or without namespace; doesn't matter" was bothering me. Other than that I understand it well.

Comment: Like I mentioned in my answer, that's simply referring to the fact that the behavior of `static` doesn't change depending on the namespace the variable is in.  `::a` in "A.cpp" is different from `::a` in "B.cpp" just like `some_ns::a` in "A.cpp" would be  different than `some_ns::a` in "B.cpp".  `::a` and `some_ns::a` are always different, since they're in different namespaces.